# Gitlab Sonar Qube Redirect Url

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube

I have a problem with authorization in Sonar Qube with Gitlab. The error is "The redirect URI included is not valid. ".My Sonar Qube is hosted on Azure VM Ubuntu. When I open the network in the browser I see that the redirect URL is "redirect_uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/callback/gitlab".Why in Gitlab Applications I put http://mysonarcubeIP/oauth2/callback/gitlab.Sonar Qube is community and Gitlab also.

Comment: In `sonar.properties` file, please add your domain name or ip in the property `http.nonProxyHosts`. Ex: **http.nonProxyHosts=mysonarcube.com|193.106.10.11**

Comment: I've exactly the same problem. I've put my sonarqube domain name but my redirect_uri is localhost:9000... It's maybe a problem with the sonarqube configuration because its default listen port is 9000 (for me, sonarqube run in a container and i've bind  0.0.0.0:57563 with 9000/tcp).

Comment: Did either of you have any success? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Try  Sourav Alta comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 8.7 (the version we have), the redirect URL is controlled by the Server Base URL, key `sonar.core.serverBaseURL`.  The description of the field mentions being used in the construction of emails, but it is also used as the callback.

You can find it in the "General" tab of the settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did work after configuring this attribute.